# Disable input of certain characters in text area

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, textarea

So i have a textArea, and i can't let the user type '%' on it; to handle this problem i did the following:

html:

```
<div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12 label-base">

                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Justificativa</label>

                <textarea style="resize: none"  ng-disabled="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.flagDesabilitaEdicaoProposta"
                          class="form-control observacoes" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" ng-model="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial"
                          onkeypress="test()">
                </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The function inside my controller:

```
 $scope.test = function () {
        var txtarea = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea1");
        txtarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
            txtarea.value = txtarea.value.replaceAll("%", "");
        })
    }
```

I'm pretty sure the logic inside the function works, but somehow the **onkeypress** attribute is not calling my function... I can still type '%' in the text area.

Any suggestion??
Don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why you are getting the textarea element using `getElementById `?
In theory you just need to use `ng-change` directive and pass your replace function. This will transform the value of your `ng-model` value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding an event listener use [ngModel.NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). You can access the property of the bind var to be updated from the controller or just pass it as a value like this example.

```
<div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
  <div class="col-md-12 label-base">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Justificativa</label>

    <textarea style="resize: none"  
      ng-disabled="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.flagDesabilitaEdicaoProposta" 
      class="form-control observacoes" 
      id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" 
      ng-model="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial" 
      ng-change="test(negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial)">
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the controller you can transform the value and assign it back to your var.

```
$scope.test = function (value) {
  negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial = value.replaceAll("%", "");
}
```